# Attribute not found after reloading the module

Tags: python, python-3.x, sockets, module, python-import

I've modified LiveOverflow's game proxy from [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iApNzWZG-10) to work with Python 3.8 (the one I'm using). However it spits out:

```
module 'parser' has no attribute 'parse'
```

whenever any packet comes through = whenever the parse function is called.
The proxy code, which is in proxy.py file, looks like this:

```
import os
import socket
from threading import Thread
import importlib
import parser

class Proxy2Server(Thread):
    def __init__(self, host, port):
        super().__init__()
        self.host = host
        self.port = port
        self.game = None
        self.server = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        self.server.connect((host, port))

    def run(self):
        while True:
            data = self.server.recv(4096)
            if(data):
                try:
                    importlib.reload(parser)
                    parser.parse(data, self.port, "server")
                except Exception as e:
                    print(f"[server:{self.port}] {e}")

                self.game.sendall(data)

class Game2Proxy(Thread):
    def __init__(self, host, port):
        super().__init__()
        self.host = host
        self.port = port
        self.server = None
        sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        sock.bind((host, port))
        sock.listen(1)
        self.game, address = sock.accept()

    def run(self):
        while True:
            data = self.game.recv(4096)
            if(data):
                try:
                    importlib.reload(parser)
                    parser.parse(data, self.port, "game")
                except Exception as e:
                    print(f"[game:{self.port}] {e}")

                self.server.sendall(data)

class Proxy(Thread):
    def __init__(self, host, destination_host, port):
        super().__init__()
        self.host = host
        self.destination_host =destination_host
        self.port = port

    def run(self):
        while True:
            print(f"[proxy:{self.port}] Setting up...")
            self.g2p = Game2Proxy(self.host, self.port)
            self.p2s = Proxy2Server(self.destination_host, self.port)
            self.g2p.server = self.p2s.server
            self.p2s.game = self.g2p.game

            self.g2p.start()
            self.p2s.start()


#Start the proxy
minecraft = Proxy("0.0.0.0", "example.com", 25565)
minecraft.start()

#Proxy command parsing
while True:
    try:
        cmd = input("$ ")

        if(cmd[:4] == "exit"):
            os._exit(0)

    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
```

The parser.py file is just:

```
def parse(data, origin, port):
    print(f"[{origin}:{port}] {data.encode('hex')}")
```

Both files are in the same directory. I don't have a clue, what could be causing this.

P.S. Yes, I'm using Minecraft to test this out.

Comment: What is the purpose of reloading the `parser` module all the time?

Comment: LiveOverflow mentions this in his video I've linked. The constant reloading is supposed to let  me see changes to the parser in real time without restarting the proxy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Python has a built-in `parser` module. It seems `import parser` is importing this instead of your local module. Try renaming your `parser.py` file to any other name and changing the `import` statement accordingly.